# ¿Por qué no puedo usar asset en Symfony 5?

Tags: symfony, symfony5

Tengo los siguiente ficheros:

base.html.twig, navbar.html.twig, reserva/index.html.twig

Una parte del fichero base.html.twig es:

```
<body>
    {% include 'navbar.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}

    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
    <!--JQuery 3.5.1-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--Bootstrap 4-->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Boostrap-select.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery widgets -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}

</body>
```

Lo que no me funciona es:

```
<a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="{{path('app_x_index')}}">
 <img class="img-responsive" src="{{asset('build/images/logo.png')}}" alt="Tu logo">
</a>
```

He estado buscando información y leí que había que colocar build/images en vez de únicamente images/

Aclaro que he instalado asset antes de esto, con: `composer require symfony/asset`

El error que recibo es:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "C:\xampp\htdocs\chapp/public/build/manifest.json" does not exist. Did you forget to build the assets with npm or yarn?").
```

Comment: corriste el comando: php bin/console assets:install

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo, el error sigue. ¿Alguna idea? ¿Qué ruta debo poner build/image o image?

Comment: la ruta es correcta? esta en tu-proyecto/build/images? proba poniendo solo image o poner el archivo en la base de tu proyecto, juga con eso y vas viendo